# Connection timeout error is happening while trying to connect Dynamo DB without proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

My application needs to connect to DynamoDB, actually my network is running behind a proxy. While trying to connect DynamoDB using below configuration **with proxy** it's is working fine.

```
#DynamoDB configuration
amazon.dynamodb.endpoint=https://dynamodb.REGIONXXXX.amazonaws.com
amazon.dynamodb.region=XXXXXXXXX
spring.data.dynamodb.entity2ddl.auto=create-only
proxy.server.address=XXXXXXXXX
proxy.server.port=31XXXXX
```

DynamoDB config:

```
@Bean
public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
    return AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withClientConfiguration(
                    PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig()
                            .withProxyHost(proxy)//we want to remove this code.
                            .withProxyPort(port))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                    new AwsClientBuilder
                            .EndpointConfiguration(amazonDynamoDBEndpoint, amazonDynamoDBRegion))
            .build();
}
```

The requirement is to connect it through using **VPC** end points, so that we believe we can connect it without any proxy.
What all are the configuration required for the same? Any code changes required rather than removing the proxy?

We have configured VPC end point with below policy:

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Principal": "*"
    }
]
```

}

But trying to connect DynamoDB with same code mentioned above(without proxy) resulting the below error:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to dynamodb.XXXXXX-1.amazonaws.com:443 [dynamodb.XXXXXXX.amazonaws.com/XX.1XX.226.XXX] failed: connect timed out
```

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Please check security group inbound rules,  Whether You IP address registered there or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DyanamoDB, like S3, uses VPC Gateway endpoints.  Once you enable the VPC Gateway you can just use a default configuration as the VPC handles routing the request from an EC2 instance out the private IP address to DynamoDB.

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
.build();
```

Note: I'm not familiar with AWS Java API so I took this above from AWS Sample code.

This assume your Security Group and VPC routing rules are correct.

Comment: standard() didn't worked for me, but the below code worked                                                         @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.defaultClient();
        return amazonDynamoDB;
    }